# can you use a wildcard character or globs in firebase with the on child_added listener?

Tags: firebase

I essentially want to do a grandchild_added event listener.

Looking at the child and the on documentation, I couldn't figure out if there was a way to set a wildcard in the reference so that it watches an entire pattern of references.

https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/api/firebase/child.html
https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/api/query/on.html

given firebase data that's like this:

```
-messages
  -roomA
    -hi a
    -hello everyone a
  -roomB
    -hi b
```

For example could I do something like this?

```
var roomMsgs = new Firebase("https://" + firebase_host + ".firebaseio.com/messages/*/");

roomMsgs.on('child_added', function(childSnapshot, prevChildKey) {
  // handle that a new message was added
});
```

I don't want to add a separate ref for every room individually if I can help it since that would be a bit more complex and I'm not sure if that would perform as well too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Nope. The `child_added` event listens one level under the location that you attach it to.

In the case you attach to a user's `messages` location, Firebase will fire a `child_changed` event and a `value` event when a message is added to a room.